# Cannot figure out if Docker is using the cache image or downloading a new image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Not clear with the docker messages regarding if the Docker is using the cache or downloading a new image.

I built an image with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk add --update redis
CMD ["redis-server"]
```

Now, upon trying to run the shell on an alpine image:
`docker run -i -t alpine sh`

I'm getting the following:

```
Unable to find image 'alpine:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
8c6d1654570f: Already exists 
Digest: sha256:82d1e9d7ed48a7523bdebc18cf6290bdb97b82302a8a9c27d4fe885949ea94d1
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:latest
```

So,

1. Why it is "Unable to find image 'alpine:latest' locally" even when the Dockerfile above pulled alpine as the base image?
2. If it is "unable" to find the image locally and "pulling" then why "Already exists" is shown ?
3. The digest and imageID is same as that of built from the Dockerfile which suggest that the image is re-used from cache; then why does it say "Downloaded newer image for alpine:latest" ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it always do the same thing? The "latest" tag will move so if there was some time between building the image and running alpine, the tag might have changed it

Comment: @LukeBriner I made sure that there was no time between building the dockerfile and then running sh on alpine image.